# Create Azure Redis Cache from code

Tags: c#, azure, redis

I want to create new azure redis cache from my C# code.
I found powershell commands that can do that but I prefer not to run powershell from code.
Do you know if there is a different way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis/) available for managing azure redis cache. You should be able to use this nuget package in your C# code. Browsing through the [powershell code on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/dev/src/ResourceManager/RedisCache/Commands.RedisCache/Commands/NewAzureRedisCache.cs), it looks like the azure powershell redis commandlet references Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis under-the-hood.